# Apache Pig : How to Compare current tuple value with prev value?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a query that needs to compare previous value of a tuple to that of current value, and mark if there is change in the value.

Input:

```
year, AccNo

1991, 1234 
1992, 1234 
1993, 1234 
1991, 1235 
1992, 1235 
1991, 1236 
1991, 1237
```

Output:

```
recyear, AccNo, firstrec
1991, 1234, 1
1992, 1234, 0
1993, 1234, 0
1991, 1235, 1
1992, 1235, 0
1991, 1236, 1
1991, 1237, 1
```

My question is: Is there any way to achieve this using builtin Pig functions that allow us to generate firstrec values based on account number?

--adding two ranks

```
rank1 = rank input BY Accno,recyear;
rank2 = rank rank1 by Accno;
```

--create first_rec

```
output = foreach rank2 generate *, ($0==$1?1:0) as first_rec;
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic that you are using to calculate the column `firstrec` in the above output?

Comment: sudar,  it doesn't seem to work properly...I want to know if we can try with any built-in functions like Stitch and Over.

Comment: I want to know the logic (I mean your requirement) so that we can suggest you how you can achieve it using Pig.

Comment: All Account number values are in sorted desc. I want to generate '1' when there is change in account number & '0' if there is no change in account number.